# Missing figure in a multicolumn environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, multicol

Consider this simple code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Figure in two column}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This code should display a circle, but somehow it doesn't.

[image]

But if we comment out `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}`, the circle appears.

[image: m]

How to fix this?

Comment: The use of `figure` and `table` is not possible inside of a `multicols` environment.

Comment: Probably you could use `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` instead of `multicols`?

Comment: If the figure can be limited to one column, you may include the figure in a centring environment, and create numbered captions using the caption or capt-of package, or using one of the KOMA-script classses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `\InsertBoxC` command from the plain TeX macro package and `\captionof{figure}{...}`, you can insert a column-wide figure at any point of the text: the current line will be terminated, then the figure inserted and finally the text will be resumed at the line following the figure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\InsertBoxC{%
\parbox[b][1.1\height]{\columnwidth}{%
 \centering \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw circle (1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Figure in two column}
}}%
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncussem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]